# Correct City Typos in R

Tags: r

I'm working with a data frame using R in which one variable is the name of a city in Texas. The data in that column were entered manually, which means there are typos in the city names. For example, the incorrect instances of "austin" are written as "austin tx", "austn", "autisn". I have a data frame of all cities, towns, villages, and CDPs (from Gazetteer files) in Texas.

My main data frame has 7,597 observations. After exploring the data, I've found 7,285 correct spellings and 305 misspellings or incorrect entries by comparing the entries to the locations listed in the Gazetteer data frame. Not all of the incorrect entries were misspellings (but most were). A few entries contain street numbers, names, or both instead of city names. I also believe that some were geographic locations not listed in the Gazetteer file (e.g., Cypress, TX).

I'm trying to find a way to correct the typos by matching them to a list of valid locations Despite spending quite a bit of time on this site and others trying to find a solution I have not been able to. Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT:

It was pointed out to me that I need to provide reproducible code in my example. I apologize for the oversight - I'm new to stackoverflow.

Below is the code I use to create my main data frame with certificant data.

```
texas_certs <- read_xlsx("Texas_cert_Data.xlsx")

#This abbreviates the full length names of the certifications.
for (i in 1:nrow(texas_certs)) {
  if (texas_certs[i, 1] == "Board Certified Behavior Analyst-Doctoral") {
    texas_certs[i, 1] <- "BCBA-D"
  } else if (texas_certs[i, 1] == "Board Certified Behavior Analyst") {
    texas_certs[i, 1] <- "BCBA"
  } else if (texas_certs[i, 1] == "Board Certified Assistant Behavior Analyst") {
    texas_certs[i, 1] <- "BCaBA"
  }
}
#Lowercase cities to make analysis easier
texas_certs$`City (Contact)` <- tolower(texas_certs$`City (Contact)`)

#Renames the columns for texas_certs
texas_certs <- texas_certs %>%
  rename(city = `City (Contact)`, country = `Country (Contact)`)
```

Below is the code for importing and modifying the Gazetteer data.

```
#Load Gazetteer files for Texas from US census.
texas_places <- read_tsv("2019_gaz_place_texas.txt")

#The name column includes the type of location that it is: city, town, village, or CDP
#First I'm going to separate out the city name and the type
#Next I'm going to create a new data frame with the data in NAME only including the location name,
#and the type of location as a separate variable.
texas_places_type <- str_extract_all(texas_places$NAME, 
                                     pattern = c(" city| town| village| CDP"))
texas_places_sep <- str_replace_all(texas_places$NAME, 
                                    pattern = c(" city| town| village| CDP"), 
                                    replacement = "")

texas_places_clean <- texas_places %>%
  mutate(NAME = texas_places_sep) %>%
  mutate(TYPE = as.character(texas_places_type))

texas_places_clean$NAME <- tolower(texas_places_clean$NAME)
```

Lastly, this code creates two data frames: one of certifications for correct city names and another for misspellings.

```
#Create list of texas locations
texas_cities <- unique(texas_places_clean$NAME)

#It looks like there are a bunch of entry errors in the city column. 
#I'll run the code below to see how many cases I would remove if I just ignored every error.
texas_certs_cleaned <- texas_certs %>%
  filter(city %in% texas_cities)

texas_certs_misspelled <- texas_certs %>%
  filter(!(city %in% texas_cities))
```

Comment: start by asking question the proper way, by providing a code that can be solved.

Comment: You should look into providing a minimally reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It does seem that you've identified all of the incorrect records, so it seems reasonable that you'd be able to subset them and then clean them up, potentially with a series of `case_when` statements using `dplyr`, or perhaps using `stringr`/regex to extract city names when possible.

Comment: @jangorecki I wasn't aware I needed to do that. I've made edits to my submission with the relevant code.

Matt thanks for the suggestions. I added what I hope counts as reproducible code. Any other suggestions based on that?